# Replacing a figure on Tkinter Python

Tags: python-2.7, canvas, tkinter, subplot

I am using Tkinter and would like to have the option to clear my graph and draw a new one in its place. I'm not sure what to put in my callback to do this.  The best I can do so far is to replace the graph with a white box. The new graph is drawn underneath (which isn't ideal) and also appears as a blank white box for some reason.  Apologies for asking such a basic question but I'm new to python and couldn't find an example using subplots on here.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk



class Helmholtz_App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Helmholtz Coils Data")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne,PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()




class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        fig1 = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = fig1.add_subplot(111)


        def callback():

            volt=[[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]]
            a.plot(volt[1],volt[0],'bo')

            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, self)
            canvas.show()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

            def ClearCallback():

                #problem line
                #~~~~~~~~~~~
                fig1.clf()
                # ~~~~~~~~~~

                clearbutton.destroy()

            clearbutton=ttk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=ClearCallback)
            clearbutton.pack()

        b=ttk.Button(self, text="Plot Data", command=callback)  
        b.pack()
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = Helmholtz_App()
app.mainloop()
```

The code is based on this tutorial [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&v=Zw6M-BnAPP0)
I want the code to work so the "take data" button creates a graph, and the "clear" button removes that graph. Then when the "take data" button is pressed again it will put a new graph in the same place with none of the data from the old graph present.

Here is the

Comment: fig2 is never initialized. So you'll have a problem until you initialize it to something useful.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, that is supposed to say fig1!  However, that doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: What is your clue that `fig1.clf()` is the problem line? Please share traceback or any other pertinent information. Also, fig1 is created via a function called Figure. What graphics module other than tkinter is involved? What would really be best is the required [msve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so someone can reproduce the problem on their own system.

Comment: Hi @Ron, thanks again for your help.  I wrote that fig1.clf() is the "problem line" because this is the part of the code that isn't doing what I want it to.  "Figure" comes from "from matplotlib.figure import Figure" and this is now included as part of a msve.  I'm not sure what the traceback is/how to share it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running python 3 and the FigureCanvasTkAgg call throws an exception regarding initializing tkinter. So until that bug is fixed, I won't be able to make any suggestions.